# Access an original TemplateInstace from the helper in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper

Could anybody point me how to access an **original** `TemplateInstance` from the meteor helper. I'm aware of the `Template.instance()` but it appears to return the template instance where the helper was *called*, not the template instance for which the helper was *defined*.

Imagine we have two tiny templates:

```
<template name='demo'>
  <h1>{{helper}}</h1>
  {{# border}}
    <h2>{{helper}}</h2>
  {{/border}}
</template>

<template name='border'>
  <div style="border:1px solid red">
    {{> UI.contentBlock}}
  </div>
</template>
```

With the following behavior:

```
Template.demo.created = function() {
  this.result = "OK";
}

Template.demo.helpers({
  helper: function() {
    var tmpl = Template.instance();
    return tmpl.result || "FAILED";
  }
});
```

I've expected to obtain two "OK" for the `demo` template: the second one should be in the red border. But since Template.instance() returns original `TemplateInstance` only when helper is called at the top level of its owner template the result is "FAILED" (of course in the red border).

**Question**: Is there any **public** api to get the original `TemplateInstance` (without need to traverse `view/parentView/_templateInstace`)?

Comment: There isn't a public API that I'm aware that would let you do this. Is your above code just an example, or is it something that you are actually trying to accomplish...adding a red border around another template? Becuase if so, there is a much better way to do it.

Comment: Does not answer your question, but you could also register your instances in a global variable (in the `created` callback) and remove them when they're destroyed (`destroyed` calbback).

Comment: I wonder, is this expected behavior, or a bug? Does anyone know? I for one really expected `Template.instance()` would refer to an instance of the template the helper was attached to. Is there a use-case for when it's not?

Comment: It's just example, red border around another template isn't result I want to achieve by using this pattern.

Comment: I found [an issue about it](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2923). I didn't get if they've fixed it or not for the next version of Meteor yet, but at least they're aware of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it's known and already fixed (?) Meteor bug. More here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3745

Comment from `rclai` on GitHub:

> This was already addressed and fixed for the next release.
>
> Run meteor like this, not sure if it still works:
>   meteor --release TEMPLATE-CURRENT-DATA@0.0.1
>
> Another alternative is to use `aldeed:template-extensions`, which has super nice features, especially with dealing with template instances and I believe their way of fetching the template instance is a workaround this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is that you not setting a template instance variable correctly. Try the below code...

Set an instance variable:

```
Template.instance().result.set("OK");
```

Get an instance variable:

```
Template.instance().get("result");
```

So your updated code would be:

```
Template.demo.created = function() {
    Template.instance().result.set("OK");
}

Template.demo.helpers({
    helper: function() {
        return Template.instance().get("result") || "FAILED";
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried this on MeteroPad. I get an error because result isn't defined.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the problem is that `Template.instance()` will refer to a template instance of `border` the second time `helper` is called, and this suggested solution won't make any difference to the original code in that case.

Comment: @RamsayLanier Whoops I forgot the quotes. My bad! :) I have updated the code above.

Comment: That's not my case. `result` is not ReactiveVar. But I have tried with ReactiveVars and `result.set("OK")`. It doesn't work as well. I feel it's Meteor's bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this might be to either just set a Session variable, or use a Reactive Variable (using the reactive-var package - [here is the documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar)).

I've made a meteor pad to show how this more - [here](http://meteorpad.com/pad/q6XrdZ4JNsBFThj5Y/Parent%20Template%20Check).

Basically:

```
Template.demo.created = function() {
    result = new ReactiveVar('OK');
}

Template.demo.helpers({
    helper: function() {
        return result.get() || "FAILED";
    }
});
```

Comment: You should make `result` a local variable rather than global. However, the downside with this solution is that it may not work if you have multiple instances of the template (they all share the same `result` variable).

Comment: You're correct - but you pass an argument through the template which could set the result to different things. I dunno - these seems like a silly example anyway.

Comment: Yes, the example is silly, but it demonstrates a real problem in a simple way, which is great.